# Why "=" operator results True when comparing varEmpty with a zero evalued varInteger?

Tags: delphi, operators, delphi-2007, variant

Why does the `=` operator results `True` when comparing a `varEmpty` `Variant` variable with a zero evalued `varInteger` `Variant` variable?

```
var
  V1 : Variant;
  V2 : Variant;
begin
  V2 := 0;
  if(V1 = V2)
  then ShowMessage('V1 = V2')
  else ShowMessage('V1 <> V2');
end;
```

This code produces the following output:

> V1 = V2

Does the equality operator `=` only checks the value part of `Variant` variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to make a comparison, the empty variant is converted to an integer. According to the [variant type conversion rules](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Variant_Types_(Delphi)#Variant_Type_Conversions), the unassigned (empty) variant is converted to 0. Hence the expression returns true.